# ffmpeg recording video with capture video (HDMI to USB), the video recorded splatter

Tags: usb, ffmpeg, video, hdmi, recording

I use **capture video HDMI to USB and has output USB and HDMI**

[Device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aSuz.png)

I use the ffmpeg with "below code". The recording was working with a raspberry pi or TV box worked without issues with **USB output** in the PC.

```
ffmpeg -y -f dshow -s 1920x1080 -r 60 -i video="USB Video" -c:v libx264 C:\output\output.mp4 -s 1920x1080 -r 60  -c:v rawvideo -f nut - | "ffplay" - -autoexit
```

The problem is I use the same code with another device, and the recording was recorded with splatter as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dtGw.jpg) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSkC0.jpg)

To be sure that the issue is not under the capture recording, I use the HDMI output to the same TV I used it with the PC. and [it worked without issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RW3ZD.jpg)

Comment: Those devices are essentially webcams - can you confirm that its not the device at fault by using it with the camera app on your device?

Comment: I'm hysteroscopy device:  **ENDOCAM Logic HD Lite camera controller**

[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HYQjgV0OcZex9UYyZ8dWfb-TSfaHBwK1/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Oh! I thought you meant the capture card, which is something I am very familiar with - I use that model and a later one extensively. Does the device output to HDMI or USB? Are you meaning you're connecting the  endoscope to a capture card and its picking up noise?

Comment: The **ENDOCAM Logic HD Lite camera controller** records the videos in a USB port with bad quality, for that, I'm using the HDMI output of this device **"This output is for  TV"**  but I'm using it to record the video by **capture video HDMI to USB **  with FFmpeg code with HD quality, but it works with the issue. as you know the **capture video HDMI to USB ** has input HDMI and 2x output USB and HDMI, the output HDMI was not shown this noise with the same TV. I don't know what the issue is the frequency or the ffmpeg code. and what's the solution.

Comment: How is it when you monitor the output of the video capture box using the camera app of your OS ? Do you have the same noise? If you have the same noise there, its not your code - its an issue between the capture box and the camera controller. If not you can try to work out why ffmpeg is giving issues

Comment: is by my code and also the same issue was recorded by VLC player in the windows. but why this noise was not shown in the output HDMI in the same box.

Comment: In which case its probably not your code - if VLC catches the same issue. I'd guess its some incompatibility between the video capture card and the controller? You can't really change anything on the video capture card side IIRC  - so I'd wonder if there's any options on the camera controller you can experiment with?

Comment: in the manual was not, I change other capture video HDMI to USB has single output that shown the same issue but maybe in the same supplier, I will try to buy another one.